# How to trace error 3228369022 (0xc06d007e) 'Module not found'?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a C# Winforms CMS application which maintains data in an Access database via OleDb and posts elements of it to a web backend. My issue seems to be the same as the one found here:
[SO question on tracing a 'module not found' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75404844/how-can-i-find-the-source-of-a-module-not-found-crash-after-no-user-activity)
in that I too run my application then it bombs out after about 20 seconds with the 'module not found' error.

I can't identify anything that I have changed in the code that could have triggered this; I've basically been working on refining the population of a list in a form with data retrieved from the db - something I've been doing extensively throughout development - and besides the occasional application crash which I've "solved" by restarting VS2022, things have been going OK. No new classes have been created prior to the onset of the issue.

The crash seems to be entirely time driven - i.e. it makes no difference what I do in the UI. A "catch all" `try...catch` in Program.cs does not catch any exception.

The searches that I have done with the error number seem to reference an issue with Kernelbase.dll but alas I am sufficiently unskilled to establish how/where my code references this library. A contributor to the referenced question suggests "capture a crash dump and analyze it with WinDbg", but (having read the MS page on getting started with WinDbg) I literally have no idea how I would do this, or what I would be looking for.

On the advice found on an MS forum, I ran "`sfc /SCANNOW`" which "found corrupt files and successfully repaired them". This had no apparent impact on the issue.

Please could you point me in the direction where I might find out what is going on and how to fix it?

Z

PS/ This may be the same error as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271258/delay-load-dll-exception-0xc06d007e-module-not-found-when-application-starte) too - but I'm not explicitly/knowingly calling any new dll, nor working in c++.
PPS/ This is happening again and I can't work around - with the only change that I can think of being a Windows Update. Now I have a Process Monitor dump, how do I go about finding the 'module'?

Comment: You can use [FusLogvw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) or [WinDbg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/windbg-overview)

Comment: A 20 second timeout sound more like a timeout occurring while app is trying to get authorization to a remote machine from a Password Server.  You are using Windows Credentials and all your machines are in the same Windows Group.  There are one or more Password servers that give access to remote machines.  Occasionally Timeouts will occur when attempting a remote connection.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng - I'll take a look at that. I do have a call to WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() that I can remark out.

Comment: You need a stacktrace at a minimum. Doesn't the application event log have a crash record? Setup user mode dumping if you haven't already: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps and you might need to bite the bullet and get up to speed with windbg. Do note that MS Access is a COM based application and with its OLE driver that loads into the process memory of your app.  That brings in a **LOT** of dependencies that all might have several fail cases, ending in the conclusion that its not your app fault a crash happens.

Comment: Microsoft has some deep dive videos in windbg in their Defrag Tools show: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Shows/Defrag-Tools/?terms=windbg those, take you from beginner level into more advanced features as you go.

Comment: Thank you @rene. That has given me some avenues to follow. Whilst the application relies on it's database interaction, I could start by temporarily disabling the call I make in Program.cs to make the connection to it and see if it changes anything.  Remarking out calls to WindowsIdentity didn't make a difference, so it looks likely that I'm going to be acquiring some basic WinDbg skills! :)

Comment: _posts elements of it to a web backend._: What does this mean? The following may (or may not) be helpful: [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2)

Comment: _besides the occasional application crash which I've "solved" by restarting VS2022, things have been going OK_:  You may consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and posting it on SO. Without any code, it's impossible to know why you're experiencing issues.

Comment: 0xc06d007e is generated for a delay-loaded DLL that, when needed, could not be found by the OS.  Diagnosing needs to start by first identifying the name of that DLL, next where exactly it looked for the file.  Both tasks are most easily done by SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll get a big trace, given the delay, work backwards.

Comment: OK guys. I now have WinDbg installed and have made the requisite registry changes to capture a dump file which I have loaded into WinDbg. This gives me a call stack (which is not as familiar to me as the call stack within VS but I get that it is showing the hierarchy of calls leading to the error.) Not sure what the etiquette is regarding posting large chunks of debug analysis, but my (noob) reading of what I see on the screen is that the issue occurs with mso.dll - which a little detective work shows to be a microsoft office library. I get: APPLICATION_FAULT_c06d007e_mso.dll!Unknown.

Comment: mso.dll appears to have updated on the 15th of this month - presumably as part of Office Update. Does this suggest a compatibility issue with the latest file or am I being over-simplistic?

Comment: Yep. Sure enough, no database initialisation, no crash. But no useful application either, so I don't know how to proceed (other than to port the db to mySQL and re-write my data access layer).

Comment: Unfortunately, your post lacks details such as Office version, OS version, and last but not least, a  [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing. Due to the lack of any useful information in your post, it's unclear whether or not the following article would be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @user246821. This is a C# (VS Community 2022) winforms application on a Win10 Pro machine seeking to use a local db created in Access for Microsoft 365 v2302 64bit via OleDB. Your linked article seems to imply that my application would never have worked - which is not the case (& I don't encounter the errors listed); as described, I experienced seemingly random 'module not found' errors which I can neither "try/catch" in my code or (as yet) trace the PM dump - which may be just my not knowing what to look for. An MRE may be quite large but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Did you read the information in the pink box? Did you install any MS Access runtime libraries? You may consider installing the _Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime_  specified in the article to see if you still experience the issue.

Comment: Also perhaps worthy of mention: I'm using System.Data.OleDb version 8.0.

Comment: I did read the pink box, but it doesn't appear to apply and requires uninstalling Access from my machine. I did NOT install any MS Access runtime libraries afaik.  The table above the pink box seems to me to suggest that running Office 365 means no additional installations are required.

Comment: You stated: that you're using [System.Data.OleDb version 8.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/8.0.0). Are you using  [.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) or [.NETFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/microsoft-net-framework)? What version?

Comment: .NET 7.0. Fingers crossed, the installation of the Access 2013 Runtime seems to have done it - so thank you @user246821. Having said that, I really don't understand why (if this is needed) it worked before, and why it then stopped working except when Access was not running locally and then why it stopped entirely.

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you may consider using the _Repair Office_ option.

Comment: What's your [Connection String](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/). Also your application bitness (32-bit/64-bit) should match your Office bitness.

Comment: The following post shows how to determine the versions of _ACE_ that are installed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950023/10024425 which is specified in your connection string.

Comment: Thanks for all the additional tips & links, @user246821. It does appear to be working happily alongside Access now. Connection string is "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = [redacted].accdb;". I'll post again if anything relevant turns up resulting from your suggested actions.

Comment: The _Provider_ should not necessarily be _12.0_,  see the chart [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Database_Engine) (under _History_ section). Run the _PowerShell_ command mentioned in the post in my previous comment to determine the correct value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bingo!
It turns out that the issue lies somewhere in MS Office - probably within mso.dll. I'm sure there's a responsible way to go, reporting the issue to Microsoft along with a reproducible code example - but I'm on a mission with my project, so I sidestepped it by following the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841) to revert Office to Version 16.2302 Build 16130.20332.
This has entirely eliminated the crash.

Many thanks to all who helped along the way - particularly @rene who got down to my level. :)

Z

PS/ If anyone can give me a pointer as to how to report the issue, maybe I'll get back to it when I'm done.

Comment: Just a brief update in case anyone ends up with this problem too. Everything was tolerably stable for quite a while until this identical problem recurred. I installed and 'analysed' with SysInternals Process Monitor but couldn't establish which of the many dlls that are called for was the 'module not found'. However, if I close Access before running my code, it works without error. I seem to be able to then load Access and have both running simultaneously. I have therefore let office update run without further issue.

Comment: Could I pick your brains again, please? This has recurred (after a Windows update maybe?) and now no amount of closing Access or any other Office app prevents it. I have my Process Monitor dump but need help with knowing what/when to look for within it. Will the 'Module not found' item show at the time it was requested or when the error was raised? Should I be looking for a "Name not found" error or something else? Many thanks.