Microsoft .ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered in the local machine
I developed a system using VB.net 2010 & access 13 DB. when i moved the system in to another computer it gives the "Microsoft .ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered in the local machine"
my new computer doesn't install the MS office. it uses the o365 office applications.
I installed access DB engine in several times but it gave the same error as above.
Can anyone please help to sort this issue.
Thank you

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950023/10024425

What platform does your project target? Chances are that it is targeting x86 and it worked before because you had 32-bit Office installed on that machine. You almost certainly now have 64-bit Office installed, so your 32-bit app cannot see a 32-bit ACE provider. Microsoft used to default to installing 32-bit Office but now it defaults to 64-bit. You have multiple options, but you need to be aware of what the ramifications are.
If you want to keep your project targeting x86 then you're going to need to install 32-bit ACE. You can do that but it cannot be the same version as the 64-bit ACE you already have installed. Last I looked, you could download the Office 2016 and Office 2010 ACE providers, but you cannot install both the 32-bit and 64-bit editions of the same version. You can try to install the 32-bit edition of the latest version you can find and it will refuse if that version is already installed, in which case you can try an older version. If you do this, your app will remain 32-bit and so will only work on other machines that have 32-bit ACE installed.
You can change the target platform for the project to Any CPU and then it will work with what you already have installed. That's because the app will run in a 64-bit process on your 64-bit OS and so will look for a 64-bit ACE provider. The same will happen on any other 64-bit OS, so they would also have to have 64-bit ACE installed. The app would still work on 32-bit OSes (which are pretty rare these days) with 32-bit ACE installed. I think that the app should also run natively on ARM processors, but I'm not sure what the situation is with Office on ARM. I don't know whether it is native or emulated, so not sure whether your app would be able to see ACE.
If you want your app to work on every combination of OS and ACE provider then you'll need to build at least twice. You'll need an x86 build to run on a 64-bit OS with 32-bit ACE, an x86 or Any CPU build to run on a 32-bit OS and an x64 or Any CPU build to run on a 64-bit OS with 64-bit ACE.
