The "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider is not registered on the local machine
I'm using Automation Anywhere 360 where i'm calling database connect for Excel using AA360 Action (Database connect) and this is working as expected . But when i'm calling the same via console app it is throwing error "The "MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider is not registered on the local machine". 
Note: I've installed Access Access Database Engine 2016 and running console application on 32bit

Which ACE driver have you installed - 32 or 64 bit?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77950023/10024425, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution, and https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/access-blog/breaking-ace-out-of-the-bubble/ba-p/1167712
